# Proper usage of `getProgramAccounts` via Rust SDK. Cannot execute RPC call from SDK

Tags: rust, rpc, solana-client-sdk

I want to list all user accounts for a given SPL mint token. I have been following the docs [over here](https://spl.solana.com/token#finding-all-token-accounts-for-a-specific-mint)

I can manage to execute the RPC call from the CLI using curl (notice I am using my own pre-deployed SPL token)

```
curl http://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 165
          },
          {
            "memcmp": {
              "offset": 0,
              "bytes": "tmyjPipMS9jHkmhibbepduYAWpdrv5qkEqGz5fm4PQN"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

Expected output

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"account":{"data":{"parsed":{"info":{"isNative":false,"mint":"tmyjPipMS9jHkmhibbepduYAWpdrv5qkEqGz5fm4PQN","owner":"5Jja5kAvCFkixQSQhKpKWgWRx8FX6eh3FXH7oqJ98x7","state":"initialized","tokenAmount":{"amount":"100000000000","decimals":9,"uiAmount":100.0,"uiAmountString":"100"}},"type":"account"},"program":"spl-token","space":165},"executable":false,"lamports":2039280,"owner":"TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA","rentEpoch":361},"pubkey":"2qWFXQyFBLuzUGveSaEajojPVjUtLAjRM8QCWu34NUe2"}],"id":1}
```

But I am having trouble translating this to Rust code:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::str::FromStr;

    use solana_client::{
        rpc_config::RpcProgramAccountsConfig,
        rpc_filter::{Memcmp, MemcmpEncodedBytes, RpcFilterType},
    };

    use super::*;

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn testing() {
        // Test code snippet
        let rpc = RpcClient::new("https://api.devnet.solana.com".to_string());
        // Step 1 Assume that I have the data here.
        let token_account =
            Pubkey::from_str("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA").unwrap();
        let mint_account = Pubkey::from_str("tmyjPipMS9jHkmhibbepduYAWpdrv5qkEqGz5fm4PQN").unwrap();

        let filters = vec![
            RpcFilterType::DataSize(165),
            RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_base58_encoded(0, &mint_account.to_bytes())),
        ];
        let filters = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
            filters: Some(filters),
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let all_user_accounts = rpc
            .get_program_accounts_with_config(&token_account, filters)
            .await;
        println!("{all_user_accounts:?}");
// Err(ClientError { request: Some(GetProgramAccounts), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32600, message: "Encoded binary (base 58) data should be less than 128 bytes, please use Base64 encoding.", data: Empty }) })
    }
}
```

Changing the filters to use Base64 encoding results in a different error:

```
        let filters = vec![
            RpcFilterType::DataSize(165),
            RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp {
                offset: 0,
                bytes: MemcmpEncodedBytes::Base64(mint_account.to_string()),
                encoding: None,
            }),
        ];
   // Err(ClientError { request: None, kind: RpcError(RpcRequestError("RPC node on old version does not support base64 encoding for memcmp filters")) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way how I managed to retrieve the data I wanted, was to bypass the `get_program_accounts` helper on the SDK client, as it was unable to properly parse the returned data. Here is the code that returns the expected result.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::str::FromStr;

    use serde_json::json;
    use solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding;
    use solana_client::{
        rpc_client::RpcClient,
        rpc_config::{RpcAccountInfoConfig, RpcProgramAccountsConfig},
        rpc_filter::{Memcmp, MemcmpEncodedBytes, RpcFilterType},
        rpc_request::RpcRequest, rpc_response::RpcKeyedAccount,
    };
    use solana_sdk::{commitment_config::{CommitmentLevel, CommitmentConfig}, pubkey::Pubkey};

    #[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]
    async fn testing() {
        let rpc = RpcClient::new("https://api.devnet.solana.com".to_string());
        let token_account =
            Pubkey::from_str("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA").unwrap();
        let mint_account = Pubkey::from_str("tmyjPipMS9jHkmhibbepduYAWpdrv5qkEqGz5fm4PQN").unwrap();

        let filters = vec![
            RpcFilterType::DataSize(165),
            RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_raw_bytes(0, mint_account.to_bytes().to_vec())),
        ];
        let filters = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
            filters: Some(filters),
            account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
                encoding: Some(UiAccountEncoding::JsonParsed),
                data_slice: None,
                commitment: Some(CommitmentConfig {
                    commitment: CommitmentLevel::Finalized,
                }),
                min_context_slot: None,
            },
            ..Default::default()
        };
        let all_user_accounts = rpc.send::<Vec<RpcKeyedAccount>>(
            RpcRequest::GetProgramAccounts,
            json!([token_account.to_string(), filters]),
        );
        println!("{all_user_accounts:?}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the first error message, it complains about the returned data being too large for base58.

// Err(ClientError { request: Some(GetProgramAccounts), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32600, message: "Encoded binary (base 58) data should be less than 128 bytes, please use Base64 encoding.", data: Empty }) })

To make your first snippet work you need to specify your encoding.

```
    let config = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
        filters: Some(filters),
        account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
            encoding: Some(UiAccountEncoding::JsonParsed), // This is necessary to avoid 
            data_slice: None,
            commitment: Some(CommitmentConfig {
                commitment: CommitmentLevel::Finalized,
            }),
            min_context_slot: None,
        },
        ..Default::default()
    };
```

This is what your solution had except that you don't need to do all the work manually you can use the original `rpc.get_program_accounts_with_config`

An example in a get_account call where it isn't using the default encoding
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9fb7ec77c8aa444544c4dd20497d92c9f378ea4f/client/src/nonblocking/rpc_client.rs#L3911

Comment: The request does get executed, but there's another error, which originates from the `parse_keyed_accounts` function:
`Err(ClientError { request: Some(GetProgramAccounts), kind: RpcError(ParseError("Account from rpc")) })
`

So it seems that even though the request gets executed and the data gets returned, the Solana client instance cannot properly parse the returned data.